# How could I pass enum object with nested enum in it to a method as parameter?

Tags: java, enums, coding-style

Suppose we have an enum object like this:

```
public enum Action
{
    FOO,
    BAR;
    public enum Move
    {
         UP,
         DOWN,
         LEFT,
         RIGHT 
    }
}
```

and a method like this:

```
private void useThisEnum(Action a) {
    //code
}
```

In my Eclipse the method could not accept the enum object with the nested enum. How could I pass it? Should I always use method overloading and declare another method like this:

```
 private void useThisEnum(Action.Move ma) {
    //code
}
```

Or should I use an Interface instead of the outside enum?

Comment: This is completely different argument. The `Move` is not "subclass" of `Action` so yes, you must declare another method. `Move` is an Inner class of `Action`, but that is something else.

Comment: Okey thank you. Should remove this question?

Comment: just mark my answer as correct if someone would be searching for similar issue. I have moved my comment to the answer below

Comment: I will but you should add it as an answer cause i can not mark comment as answer.

Comment: I have already done that :) .

Comment: There is a time limit, after that I could mark it. (The limit is now 10 minutes so don't worry. :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is completely different argument. The `Move` is not "subclass" of `Action` so yes, you must declare another method. `Move` is an Inner class of `Action`, but that is something else.